# Angular cannot access component before initialize after migrating to standalone

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I follow the 3 steps to convert everything to standalone and everything seems ok.

https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration#migrations-steps

I just manually move the routes into the `main.ts` and use `provideRouter` as one `provider` to provide routing.

Yet the error starts to show. A nested component 'X' cannot be initialized.

So after some research, seems it's related to circular import because `X` uses a component which is used somewhere nested in the parent component.

Well, if this is the case... Seems it's just not a good idea for me to even try to convert to standalone.

I mean even I can solve this and I appreciate if someone can enlighten the way.  I did try `forwardRef`, it did not work.

But to me, it's a mess anyway to move forward it seems. I might be better off sticking to the `NgModule`?

I don't know how I got the idea that standalone is the direction we are going. Somewhere the doc gave me that impression I think.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Post some code or a minimal reproduction in stackblitz pls

Comment: Added a screenshot regarding the specifics. It's converting from NgModule to Standalone so unless someone has met it, this might not tell too much. But this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by `Circular Dependencies`.

In my case, `static initializer` ( from screenshot) already revealed the component which required using `forwardRef( () => MovieListComponent)` change. I didn't pay enough attention.

https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#dependency-injection-and-injectors-hierarchy

For big project, this issue surely will rise.